# Access governor limits values for managed package via Apex

Tags: apex, governorlimits

So the `system class Limits` is available to get the number of any limits against an org.
For performance tuning and logging perspective, is it possible to get the Limits for an installed managed package, as it has its own governor limits.

We get those values in the logs if we turn on profiling, but is there a way I can access the Limits values through Apex? 
For example, I want to use it for the Field Service Lightning package(FSL) from Salesforce. So to do something like FSL.Limits.getQueries().

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not. A managed package can call the Limits methods to get "their version" of the limits (e.g. queries they've used and have left), but there's no way to get at these values during runtime outside of the package. You'd have to query and parse the logs (if available). You'll probably want to [submit an idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch). I already did a search and did not immediately find such an idea already, so it probably does not exist as of yet.

Comment: Great thanks sfdcfox. Wanted the confirmation from the pro :)